# Javascript - Extract data from html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to extract the **headers data** and column data **(not row data)** from an HTML table using JavaScript.

Is this a good approach of doing it? And how can I simplify this using jQuery?

```js
let table = document.getElementById('tab')
debugger
let headers = Array.from(table.rows[0].cells).map(x => x.innerText)
let columnData = 
Array.from(table.rows).
      slice(1, table.rows.length).
      map(row =>Array.from(row.cells).map(x => x.innerText))
     .reduce((acc,rowData)=>{
           rowData.forEach((value,index)=>{
           acc[index]= acc[index] || [ ]
           acc[index].push(value) })
      return acc },[])
console.log(headers)
console.log(columnData)
```

```html
<table id="tab">
  <tr>
    <th>
      Name
    </th>
    <th>
      Age
    </th>
    <th>
      Location
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>
      Jason
    </th>
    <th>
      22
    </th>
    <th>
      Texas
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      Lawson
    </th>
    <th>
      21
    </th>
    <th>
      Florida
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      Jose
    </th>
    <th>
      25
    </th>
    <th>
      London
    </th>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Always use `const`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278652/how-much-should-i-be-using-let-vs-const-in-es6) to declare variables - only use `let` when you must reassign. This keeps code readable, because then a reader of the code doesn't have to constantly keep in mind that a variable might be reassigned later. (If you use `let` but then *don't* reassign, it can still be confusing - in professional code, one might think "Why is `let` being used here? Was this meant to be reassigned in a section of code that was later removed, or something?)

`Array.from` accepts an optional mapper function as a second parameter. Any time you have:

```
Array.from(arrayLike).map(mapper)
```

you may replace it with

```
Array.from(arrayLike, mapper)
```

(If all you're doing is converting an array-like object into an array, some prefer spread syntax because it's even more concise: `[...arrayLike]`)

`innerText` is a [weird property](http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/) introduced by Internet Explorer (*outside* of web standards originally) that has a number of odd quirks. Unless you're *deliberately looking* to invoke those quirks, it would be a better idea to use `textContent` instead to retrieve text from an element.

You can easily distinguish the first `tr` from the other `tr`s by using the query string `#tab tr:first-child` or `#tab tr:nth-child(n + 2)`:

```js
const headers = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('#tab tr:first-child th'),
  th => th.textContent.trim()
);
// Make an empty array for every item in headers:
const data = Array.from(headers, () => []);
for (const tr of document.querySelectorAll('#tab tr:nth-child(n + 2)')) {
  [...tr.children].forEach((th, i) => {
    data[i].push(th.textContent.trim());
  });
}
console.log(headers);
console.log(data);
```

```html
<table id="tab">
  <tr>
    <th>
      Name
    </th>
    <th>
      Age
    </th>
    <th>
      Location
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>
      Jason
    </th>
    <th>
      22
    </th>
    <th>
      Texas
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      Lawson
    </th>
    <th>
      21
    </th>
    <th>
      Florida
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      Jose
    </th>
    <th>
      25
    </th>
    <th>
      London
    </th>
  </tr>

</table>
```

That's already quite simple, IMO. I think adding jQuery to the mix would make things unnecessarily more complicated, not less.

I refactored it out, but I don't think it's good idea to use `reduce` when the accumulator is going to be the same object every time. See: [Is `reduce` bad?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaGjS7-qWzg) by Google devs. If it's always going to be the same object, it'll be a bit easier to read if that object is declared as a standalone variable in the outer scope.

The HTML is a bit weird. A `<th>` is a *table header*. It makes sense for the headers to be `<th>`s, but the table *data* should probably be `<td>`s instead.

Comment: Hey there @CertainPerformance. This answer is cool . Let me understand and learn from it. Actually i was lazy to write the <tr> again and again.i copied it and changed the values.forgot to make it td.

Comment: Hey i forgot @CertainPerformance.it should output column data actually.not row data.Please run my snippet to understand